# JSF - actionListener tag calls method which doesn't take an ActionEvent parameter

Tags: jsf, methods, primefaces, arguments, el

I keep reading posts which say that ActionListener methods must have the following signiture:

```
public void calledByActionListener(ActionEvent e) {
}
```

Invoked like so:

```
<p:commandButton value="Example" id="example" process="@this" ajax="false" 
    actionListener="#{exampleBean.calledByActionListener()}">
```

However I have a no-arg method like this which works:

```
public void calledByActionListener() {
}
```

**Did something change?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the new [EL 2.2](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) feature of invoking methods with custom arguments. Basically, you're explicitly invoking an argumentless method. This construct is legit.

Note that this is not related to JSF2. EL 2.2 just happens to be part of Java EE 6 as well like JSF2. So it *look like* a new JSF2 feature. But it actually isn't. As evidence, JSF2 is backwards compatible with Java EE 5 which thus implies EL 2.1, but this construct doesn't work over there.

When not explicitly specifying any custom arguments in the method expression, JSF will as per the specification assume a default argument of `ActionEvent` in the actual method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is this to say, actionListener="#{exampleBean.calledByActionListener()}" over EL2.2 is valid however actionListener="#{exampleBean.calledByActionListener}" (no brackets) would assume a default Argument of ActionEvent?

Comment: That's correct. If you explicitly specify any arguments by parentheses, it would override the default signature. Even if it's an argumentless one `()`. The same applies to `action` methods by the way, which already defaults to an argumentless one.