# How do I iterate over a sublist with ui:repeat?

Tags: jsf-2

I'm migrating a piece of legacy code that looks like this:

```
<c:forEach items="#{sel}" var="crit" end="12">
  <tr>
    <td class="criteriaName">
      <c:set var="tip" value="#{Factory.makeTooltip(crit.string)}" />

      <c:if test="#{0 != fn:length(tip)}">
        <a:outputPanel layout="block">
          <h:outputText value="#{crit.kriterium}" styleClass="tooltipAvailable"/>
            <rich:tooltip layout="block">
              <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{tip}" />
            </rich:tooltip>
         </a:outputPanel>
       </c:if>

       <c:if test="#{0 == fn:length(tip)}">
         <h:outputText value="#{crit.kriterium}" />
       </c:if>
     </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Now I'm looking to replace `<c:if>` and `<c:forEach>` with their `<ui:fragment>` and `<ui:repeat>` counterparts. Problem is, I need to iterate over `sel` twice: once from 0 to 12 and then from 13 to the end.

I haven't found a way to split the list iteration the way the `end` attribute of the foreach  tag does it. I'd really like to avoid splitting the list in the backend as this is a pure view issue and should be handled there.

So the question is: can i replace the above fragment the way I specified? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using EL 2.2, you can invoke normal java methods.

Assuming that `sel` is a `List` here, you can use

```
<ui:repeat var="crit" value="#{sel.subList(0,12)}">
```

Not that `ui:repeat` and `c:forEach` are not always interchangeable, so make sure your use case is valid.

Comment: so simple, so effective :-)

Comment: The first statement is incorrect and misleading. This is not a JSF 2.x feature at all. This is an EL 2.2 feature. JSF 2.x can be deployed to Servlet 2.5 / EL 2.1 containers which do not support this feature at all. On the other hand, JSF 1.x can be deployed to Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 containers which support this feature. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382466/jsf-actionlistener-tag-calls-method-which-doesnt-take-an-actionevent-paramete/14382966#14382966

Comment: @BalusC indeed you're right.  I was under the impression JSF2 'required' EL2.2, but apparently this is not true.  I edited the post.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Since this is (still) a Seam project, I wonder why I have been using begin/end when I could have leveraged EL. Anyway, thanks!