# Why commandButton actionListener doesn't work?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, actionlistener

I have the following code in the `login.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head><title>Login</title></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="loginBtn"  value="Login" type="submit" actionListener="#{userMB.login}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And I have I have the following bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userMB")
@RequestScoped
public class UsersManagedBean implements Serializable {
    public void login(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("print here...");
    }
}
```

I don't get the message printed because the `login()` method hasn't been invoked. Is there anything wrong?

The web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID"
   version="2.5">    
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern> *.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you place p:commandButton inside h:form? Please show your all of login.xhtml code.

Answer (score 2):

I've copied your complete example login.xhtml page to my testproject and it works fine. The managed bean I've created myself.

Did you try to avoid primefaces? Use the standard JSF implementation and try again:

```
<h:commandButton id="loginBtn"  value="Login" type="submit" actionListener="#{userMB.login}"/>
```

Notice the `<h:` instead of `<p:` for the `commandButton`.

By the way: `type="sumbit"` is the default in PrimeFaces and it should not make any difference to omit or use this attribute with the value `submit` (PrimeFaces User Guide 5.1, page 108).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.

xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head><title>Login</title></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton id="loginBtn" 
                             value="Login" 
                             type="submit" 
                             actionListener="#{userMB.login}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

managedbean

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "userMB")
@RequestScoped
public class UsersManagedBean implements Serializable {

    public void login(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("print here...");
    }
}
```

Comment: why declare the login method with a parameter of `ActionEvent event`? it should also work with no parameters.

Comment: @tt_emrah actionListener attribute will accept with a ActionEvent parameter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener.

Comment: @wittakarn but it also works without using an ActionEvent parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382466/jsf-actionlistener-tag-calls-method-which-doesnt-take-an-actionevent-paramete

Comment: @tt_emrah you will see at the question, the owner did not use login with bracket. Thus, a method will accept with a ActionEvent parameter.

Comment: i missed that, sorry. i should go back and investigate how i managed to use it without the paranthesis.

Comment: @wittakarn thank you for the tip. 
I was using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880017/javax-faces-interpret-empty-string-submitted-values-as-null-does-not-work-anymor to interpret empty strings as null but it prevented commandButton to call the method. Setting it to false did not work, either. I completely removed it from web.xml and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this after removing `type="submit"`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head><title>Login</title></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton id="loginBtn" value="Login" action="#{userMB.login}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And your `ManagedBean` should be like this.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "userMB")
@RequestScoped
public class UsersManagedBean implements Serializable {

    public void login() {
        System.out.println("print here...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed, but still no way.